# Problem reading data from InfluxDB 1.8 using Crosser Influx select module

Tags: influxdb

Error: Module Influx Select, 1.0.0, Index: 2 changed to status Error: Error Getting data, Reason: Forbidden.

I tried using Influx version 2.6.1, but I couldn’t get telegraf to insert a timestamp. I gave it a try in version 1.8 and was successful in adding a timestamp. However, despite being able to write to influx1.8 from crosser, I am currently unable to read data from it using the influx select module.